# Server Monitoring / Alerting application needed

Tags: linux, apache

Can anyone recommend a good (preferably free) application or service to monitor the uptime of a server? And possibly send out an alert by email or sms when it goes down? Statistics are not really needed, it's just about knowing when a server goes down.

Comment: Try this blog for some good solutions -> http://www.tecmint.com/monitorix-a-lightweight-system-and-network-monitoring-tool-for-linux/#comment-107340. I find [SeaLion](https://sealion.com) pretty good for this purpose though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how "sophisticated" tool you'd like to have (and install of course). You can use simple cron script on another server, or software designed for server monitoring. I've got experience and I can recommend you Zabbix or Nagios, but you can choose [another one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems).

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll look at the ones you mentioned. I also looked at mon.itor.us, but their free option is a bit too limited to be useful for our needs. (Also a bit too much ads) Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this
GAEAPIMonitor 
http://www.honcheng.com/2010/12/GAEAPIMonitor---Open-source-API-monitoring-tool-on-Google-AppEngine

It is open source, written in python for AppEngine, so you can just run it on your own AppEngine account. Alerts you with a Twitter DMs when server is down, content has changed or has not changed, if an API is returning an invalid JSON if it is supposed to return JSON.

Answer (score 0):

These are a few monitoring tools that you can try out

## Free solutions

1. System commands: Nothing beats default commands like top, vmstat, iostat, netstat etc when it comes to knowing the health of a system
2. [SeaLion](https://sealion.com): It is a cloudbased monitoring solution. What it does is basically execute all default system profiling commands (like top, vmstat etc) and present it in a very intuitive timeline format. It installation procedure is one of the easiest I have come across
3. [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/): Though very complicate to use and configure, it is very
   robust and most deployed solution available
4. [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/)
5. [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/)

## Paid solutions

1. [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/)
2. [Server density](http://www.serverdensity.com/)
3. [Copper Egg](http://copperegg.com/)